# Should I order a new SSL certificate if I want to use it on a different server?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate

I am using a Verysign SSL certificate on a specific machine and it will expire at the end of August. By that date I will migrate the application using the certificate on a different server (the URL will remain the same).

Should I have to order a completely new certificate, being the IP address and expiry date different or can I simply request to renew it since the URL will remain the same, hopefully reducing the involved costs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL certificates are usually issued to names, not IP addresses. Some can even be installed on multiple machines that way. So if yours is not bound to an IP-address, a renewal will be sufficient.

Comment: Having the certificate being created with CSR data, do you know whether the CSR has to be generated again also for a SSL certificate renewal? Or in that case it is not needed (even if the server changes)? Thanks.